# ORACLE - Select ROWNUM with distinct multiple COLUMNS

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi I am invoking SQL quires from java application, Since table has huge data its taking time to process from java side. Now i am invoking 1000 by 1000 records

```
SELECT t1.col1,t1.col2,t2.col1,t2.col2 FROM(SELECT rownum AS rn,
t1.col1,
t1.col2,
t2.col1,
t2.col2 FROM table1 t1,
table2 t2 WHERE t1.id=t2.id) WHERE rn BETWEEN ? AND ?;
```

But i have one more query which has distinct values like below

```
 SELECT t1.col1,t1.col2,t2.col1,t2.col2 FROM(SELECT rownum AS rn,
distinct t1.col1,
t1.col2,
t2.col1,
t2.col2 FROM table1 t1,
table2 t2 WHERE t1.id=t2.id) WHERE rn BETWEEN ? AND ?;
```

But this query is giving error, Not allowing to add rownum AS rn for distinct. Please could you help us to resolve above use case?

Comment: Do the `distinct` in a subquery.

Answer (score 2):

In an *oracle* database the `DISTINCT` key word is only allowed directly behind the `SELECT` key word or inside the `COUNT` function.

Furthermore your SQL will lead to inconsistent results since in an *oracle* database the order of records is not guaranteed without explicit `ORDER BY` clause.

you also cannot access the tabla aliases from an inner select so you have to apply column aliases if the columns in the different tables have the same column name.

The best solution would be to to add another layer of nested selects:

```
 SELECT t1_col1, t1_col2, t2_col1, t2_col2
   FROM (
    SELECT rownum AS rn, inner_tab.*
      FROM (
       SELECT distinct t1.col1 AS t1_col1,
                       t1.col2 AS t1_col2,
                       t2.col1 AS t2_col1,
                       t2.col2 AS t2_col2
         FROM table1 t1,
              table2 t2 
        WHERE t1.id=t2.id
      ORDER BY 1 -- you have to decide! 
     ) inner_tab
   ) WHERE rn BETWEEN ? AND ?;
```